# Visual Studio C# SerialPort data to ASCII - Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);

Tags: c#, serial-port, ascii

I am having an issue with data read from SerialPort being converted to ASCII.

When all data coming in on SerialPort is ASCII it all works fine and displays the readable characters all good using Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);

However when I switch to a protocol mode where the data coming in has a start of packet (0x02) followed by two length bytes followed by the ASCII bytes and lastly a CRC byte followed by end byte (0x03).  In the protocol mode 0x02, 0x03 are escaped using 0x10 and then XOR ing the escaped byte.

For some reason when in protocol mode the data does not display in ASCII and just displays junk and not a single byte is readable text.

This is strange because I can i.e. switch to another serial terminal i.e. RealTerm and see all the incoming data just fine as ASCII text.  Ofcourse some of the length bytes and CRC data is junk as not ASCII encoded since > 127 decimal.

I use:
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);

where data is the byte array of data received from SerialPort.
Any advice why this is ?

Comment: From : Encoding.ASCII To : Encoding.UTF8

Comment: Is it because you are trying to process the entire received data as ASCII without removing the control code or CRC? You need to receive the data as a byte array and do GetString() with a range of only the parts that are explicitly treated as ASCII characters.

Comment: Encoding.UTF8  does the same...